# Bit does not import the react compiler

Tags: reactjs, bit.dev

I am using a create-react-app scaffoldin tool, and I want to upload and track some components into bit.dev.

the problem comes when I try to follow the following tutorial:

https://docs.bit.dev/docs/tutorials/bit-react-tutorial

When I try to import the React compiler, and I run this

```
bit import bit.envs/compilers/react --override
```

The process hangs forever with this statement:

```
/ ensuring package dependencies
```

Since I can not compile locally I recieve compile errors remotely on bit.dev ... any ideas why it is not importing the react compiler?

Answer (score 1):

this is because you tried to import the compiler with the wrong flag.
To import a compiler, you need to run `bit import` like this:
`bit import bit.envs/compilers/react --compiler`

You can see all the optional flags here:
https://docs.bit.dev/docs/apis/cli-all#import
or running `bit import -h`.